# What is the proper way to format an error message in Spring?

Tags: spring, formatting

I'm using Spring 3.1.0.RELEASE.  How do you properly format an error message in Spring?  In my properties file, I have …

```
Incomplete.headers.fileData=The file is missing the following required header(s): %s
```

Then in my validation class, I have

```
public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
    ...
    final String missingHeadersStr = Joiner.on(",").join(missingHeaders);
    errors.rejectValue("fileData", "Incomplete.headers.fileData", new Object[] {missingHeadersStr}, "The file is missing some required headers.");
```

However, even though (through debugging) I've verified that the "missingHeadersStr" field is non-empty, all that displays on my JSP is

```
The file is missing the following required header(s): %s
```

What is the proper way to format an error message in Spring? For what its worth, I'm displaying them on the JSP like so

```
<form:errors path="fileData" cssClass="error" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html#reject%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) says:

> errorArgs - error arguments, for argument binding **via MessageFormat**
>   (can be null)

(emphasis mine).

You're giving a pattern usable with `String.format()`. But [MessageFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) doesn't use that. The patter should be:

```
The file is missing the following required header(s): {0}
```